# Preload DialogFragment

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem. I created a Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment. Now I use this code to show the DialogFragment:

```
var TransDialogFragment = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
Shape_Formation_Tutorial ShapeFormationTutorial = new Shape_Formation_Tutorial();
ShapeFormationTutorial.Show(TransDialogFragment, "ShapeFormationTutorial");
```

The problem is that I have added an animation to this dialog, but the animation isn't smooth at all, because when I try to show the Dialog, first it needs to be created. This takes too long, so I need to preload it somehow.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Did you try running the animation on`UIThread`?

Comment: Still same result!

Comment: The problem is that you are doing some heavy processing on the main thread (UI). Are you executing an erroneous task or playing with threads? can you share some of your code?

Comment: It's too many code, but I am drawing a hexagongrid on a skiasharp canvas. That could take a lot of usage!?

Comment: maybe you could creart it first when your acvitiy display,then call it show or hide

Comment: Thank you so much!